# BufferedWriter not writing anything to a file

Tags: java

I am reading a file `in.txt` and writing the numbers to a file `out.txt` until 42 is found.But in out.txt I am getting blank file.Instead if I write `System.out.println(num)` instead of `out.write(num)` I get correct result.It means that the problem is with the statement of BufferedReader.Where I am wrong?

import java.io.*;

```
class Numbers
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
                    String num;
                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
                    BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));

                    while((num=in.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        if(Integer.parseInt(num)==42)
                            break;
                        else
                            out.write(num);
                    }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Oh Shit!! How can I forget this. Maybe I should get some sleep.Thanks.Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the you are not closing the `out` stream. Change it to:

```
 BufferedReader in = null;
 BufferedReader out = null;
 try{
        String num;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));

         while((num=in.readLine())!=null)
                  {
                      if(Integer.parseInt(num)==42)
                          break;
                      else
                          out.write(num);
                  }
               out.close()
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }finally{
       try{
        if(in!=null) in.close();
        if(out!=null) out.close();
        }catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

This is because, your OutputStream buffers your data and periodically flushes it. Closing the stream not only flushes it but also makes it safe for other applications to use the file.

In your case you might expect a weird behavior (with sometimes complete write and sometimes not). This is due to the fact that BufferedWriter() tries closing it in its `finalize` method (which may or may not be called)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `FileWriter`:

```
while((num=in.readLine())!=null)
{
    if(Integer.parseInt(num)==42)
        break;
    else{
        out.write(num);
        out.flush();
    }
}
out.close();
```

Contents always need to be flushed. `close()` by itself will flush the stream for you, but it's good practice to `flush()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the stream after stop using it. Closing it will, firstly, flush the stream (all buffered data will be printed) and secondly, will release all resources the stream is using.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `out.close()` at the end of try block.

if you have `in.txt` as a very big file, then you will see some data in `out.txt`.

BufferedWriter writes only when it has enough data to flush, which is approximately equal to one block size.